# Problem with fourier package and expert option

Tags: ligatures, fourier

I am compiling some documents using pdfLaTeX and I have installed the expert Type1 files (.pfb and .pfm) for the Adobe Utopia fonts in order to use the `fourier` package with the expert option, which makes available small caps and text ("oldstyle") figures. I think the files have been installed correctly, since I get the titling face, true small caps, and text figures, but I have found that I have some problems with the ligatures ff and ffi, being replaced in the resulting pdf with V and Y, correspondingly (the ligature fl is available, though).

Besides, if I use the oldstyle option when loading the package, the lining figures do not get the right spacing, as can be seen when a number starts with the digit 1 (see 2012 in my MWE below). If I don't use that option, I don't get the text figures either with the `\textsc` command (text figures are in the same file as small caps) or with the command `\oldstyle`, or with any of the other usual approaches based on `textcomp` or `fontaxes`.

EDIT: I have changed my MWE to load the package `fonttable` and check the table of faces provided by the family I'm using. I have also added to this post my .map file for the package `fourier` with the option `expert`. While slots 28 and 29 in the table contain the ligatures for fi and ff, slots 30 and 31 - where I guess other ligatures should appear -, contain Y and Z.

I have checked that the OpenType face includes the ligature ff and the triple ligature ffi. Shouldn't they be also in the "expert" set for T1 encoding?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[expert,oldstyle]{fourier}
\usepackage{texttable}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{fontaxes}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\pdfmapline{=futr8x UtopiaExp-Regular <putr8x.pfb}
\xfonttable{T1}{\rmdefault}{m}{n}
\newpage

Use of ligatures at the office for this affair.

\textsc{0123456789}

\textsc{2012}

0123456789  17 18 2012

\end{document}
```

My .map file is fourier-utopia-expert. It is located in the path `\fonts\map\dvips\fourier` in the main folder of the MikTeX 2.9 distribution.

```
%%
%% Here is utopia-expert (commercial)
%%
futb8x UtopiaExp-Bold <putb8x.pfb
futbi8x UtopiaExp-BoldItalic <putbi8x.pfb
futbo8x UtopiaExp-Bold " .167 SlantFont " <putb8x.pfb
futr8x UtopiaExp-Regular <putr8x.pfb
futri8x UtopiaExp-Italic <putri8x.pfb
futro8x UtopiaExp-Regular " .167 SlantFont " <putr8x.pfb
futs8r Utopia-Semibold "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <puts8a.pfb
futs8x UtopiaExp-Semibold <puts8x.pfb
futsi8r Utopia-SemiboldItalic "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <putsi8a.pfb
futsi8x UtopiaExp-SemiboldItalic <putsi8x.pfb
futso8r Utopia-Semibold " .167 SlantFont TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <puts8a.pfb
futso8x UtopiaExp-Semibold " .167 SlantFont " <puts8x.pfb
futrc8r Utopia-RegularSC "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <putrc8a.pfb
futsc8r Utopia-SemiboldSC "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <putsc8a.pfb
futrd8r Utopia-Titling "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <putrd8a.pfb
futc8r Utopia-Black "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <putc8a.pfb
futc8x UtopiaExp-Black <putc8x.pfb
futco8r Utopia-Black " .167 SlantFont TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <8r.enc <putc8a.pfb
futco8x UtopiaExp-Black " .167 SlantFont " <putc8x.pfb
```

Comment: Can you add the `.log` file?

Comment: What happens with the ligatures if you add `\pdfmapline{=futr8x UtopiaExp-Regular <putr8x.pfb}` to your preamble?

Comment: @egreg: How can I attach a file to my original post?

Comment: @Ulrike Ficher: This was already in my .map file for the fourier fonts. As soon as I learn how to attach a file I will upload it to my post.

Comment: @Marcos: please test anyway. The question is if you have some other map-entries which interfere. The `\pdfmapline` command forces pdftex to use this entry.

Comment: @Marcos Just paste it in the question.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I have changed my MWE and edited my original post.

Comment: @egreg: I have edited my original post, my MWE, and appended my .map file instead of my log file. If you think the log file would be useful, just let me know and I'll append it, too.

Comment: The fonttable doesn't say more than you already know: That there is an V and the place of the ff-ligature. I can think of various reasons why this happens but it is difficult to test without the actual fonts. Where did you get the putr8x.pfb? Do you have an afm-file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The files were copied to me by a friend (dubious origin, I guess, but all my experience with his files had been perfect so far) and what I have is the pfb and the pfm files. From what I've read online, and from the availability of the other features (titling face, real small caps...), I think this should be enough -- or maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: The problem is not that you have not enough files. There is a mismatch between the encoding (glyph order) of the TeX support files and the encoding of the real font (putr8x.pfb). You could try the fourierx package (http://home.vr-web.de/was/putx.html) but I doubt that it will solve your problem. As far as I can see it encodes (for the `[osf]`-option) the ligatures like fourier. To me it looks as if an enc-file is missing as I can't see why a expert font should put a ligature at the position for the "Y". Try to contact the authors of fourier(x).